# fix wrong conflict resolution in git

Tags: git, merge

Ok so I messed up! I was working with a repo that had the following structure

```
                master
                  |
                  v
A--B--C--D--E--F--G
       \
        \
         H--I
            ^
            |
         feature
```

I was working on the `feature` branch and once I was done, I merged into `master`. This resulted in merge conflicts that I had to fix manually ... which I thought I did correctly. Today, however, my coworker told me that I have broken stuff they have developed in `F`. These broken part are unrelated to what I have added -- apparently in resolving the conflicts I've deleted a bunch of stuff.

How can I "revert" the repo such that I recover their changes while preserving mine? To make things worse, I have already deleted the `feature` branch on my local repo and its not been pushed to origin. This is what the repo looks like right now

```
                   master
                     |
                     v
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--J
```

I have tried

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
git merge origin/master --no-ff
```

hoping that would let me manually edit the merged files but it always automatically pulls the latest ...

Comment: It is because you have a `origin/master` which have merged `feature`, it is newer than your local `feature` so will be automatically merged even using `--no-ff` (actually, it is a fast-forward). If you want to re-merge `feature`, you should reset your local `master` to its last version and merge it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No worries. Nothing vital lost, it is git.

If you merged, you should have a merge commit (a commit with two parents). Are you sure about how does the history look like? Use `git log --graph` to see the structure of merges.

As you already published the merge to public repo and other developers have it, I don't recommend to use hard resets and rebases.

So, you should find your merge commit and do `git revert <sha1ofmerge> --mainline 1 --no-commit`, it will modify your local files to undo all changes you made by the merge. Then review the changes, do `git checkout <files>` for that you want to keep and leave only changes you need to do for other developers make happier. When just `git commit`.

Having the merge commit, you could restore your branch by `git branch feature <sha1ofmerge>^2`, here "^2" means second parent, i.e. when you merged feature into master.

Comment: Well the problem is I deleted `feature` branch right after merge and its not pushed to origin

Comment: @GradGuy Have you found the merge commit in the history?

Comment: @GradGuy: deleting a branch in your local repo only removes the label, not the series-of-commits; they hang around for 3 months by default.  Use `git reflog` to see if you can find the old branch-tip of your feature branch.  Paste a new label on it (with `git branch`) and you will have all your old commits back.  (In most cases @kan's `^2` will suffice, you only need this if you did something other than an ordinary merge.)

Comment: @torek `git reflog` doesn't work on a deleted branch. But he says it was merged, so he just need to find the merge commit and re-create the branch from its second parent.

Comment: @torek You are right about reflog, I forgot about log for the HEAD too, which would keep the trace of the lost branch. GradGuy, see here for more instructions: http://blag.ahax.de/post/421939327/recovering-a-deleted-branch-using-git-reflog

Answer (score 1):

You can do `git cherry-pick <SHA-F>` and reapply the changes from that commit.

If the files affected are across multiple commits you can also do

`git checkout <SHA> -- <filename>`

You can then create one commit that fixes all the files that were broken.

Since you have pushed your changes redoing the merge is not a good option.  As you want to avoid rewriting pushed history.